# Is there a way to save an outfit in GTA V single-player Story Mode?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

This really has been grinding my gears...

If you make an outfit for a character, it says your current outfit is updated. Sure, it is, but can you *save* this outfit as one of your (14?) base outfits, perhaps overriding it? That way I could (obviously) save my outfits for later, but also the character would swap between *my custom outfits* when you switch between characters.

Please tell me this is a feature already that I'm just missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the launch-day version of GTA V doesn't allow saving of outfits in your closet. There is a similar post about this on the GTA forums: http://gtaforums.com/topic/569416-savable-outfits/

Answer (score 1):

The *GTA V* single-player Story Mode does not have a "save custom outfit" feature, unlike in *GTA Online*. Also, character switching, certain missions, and cutscenes, could make the player character change their current outfit to a predefined outfit.

#### [The Character Clothes Mod](https://www.gta5-mods.com/scripts/the-character-clothes-mod-net)

If you are playing on the PC, you can install a mod that will allow you to save and load outfits — [The Character Clothes Mod](https://www.gta5-mods.com/scripts/the-character-clothes-mod-net). It can even make the player character keep their saved outfits, even if the game wants to change them in missions or cutscenes.

[image: screenshot of the mod]

> ##### Requirements
>
> 1. GTA V Latest Version
> 2. [ScripthookV](http://www.dev-c.com/gtav/scripthookv/)
> 3. [ScripthookVDotNet](https://www.gta5-mods.com/tools/scripthookv-net)
> 4. [NativeUI](http://gtaforums.com/topic/809284-net-nativeui/)
> 5. MadMilkman.ini.dll (included in archive)
> 6. TeamCore.dll (included in archive)
>
> ###### Installation
>
> 1. Drag and drop all files into your scripts folder.
>
> ###### Updating
>
> On upgrading you will no longer wear the saved clothing!
>
> 1. Remove previous version files especially the .ini file.
> 2. Drag and drop all files into your scripts folder.
>
> ###### Usage
>
> - Open the menu by pressing <kbd>O</kbd>. This is "O" from Odella and not zero.
> - Select if you want to have your characters clothes spawned on switching of the characters.
> - Set the persistence option on if you want to have the clothes always on no matter what.
> - The startup option allows the script to load the players clothes when the game starts or loads.
> - The duffel bag adds a bit of extra realism too the game by limiting the amount of weapons you can carry concealed. With this option on you
>   can carry all melee weapons and up to 5 small firearms. Any more
>   firearms or large firearms will make the duffel bag show.
> - You can save the settings of the menu so that on next launch you won't have to worry about it.
> - Then you have a save button which saves your current set of clothes.
> - The load button loads the saved clothes.

<sup>Source: https://www.teamcoremods.com/mods/the-character-clothes-mod</sup>

[The Character Clothes Mod](https://www.gta5-mods.com/scripts/the-character-clothes-mod-net) in action:

[image: GTA V The Character Clothes Mod][image: GTA V The Character Clothes Mod]

Notice that all three characters are not using their mission nor cutscene outfits, but the custom outfit I've set them. You can even set your character to be shirtless with the mod before the point where the game allows you to.

Answer (score -1):

You can save custom outfits by walking into your walk-in closet.